# Objective-C Transform to X and Y

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I have been researching CGAffineTransforms and was wondering if there was a way to take your view and zoom in on an x,y coordinate.  I have the scaling portion down with the function:

```
       CGAffineTransformMakeScale(4.00 ,4.00);
```

However I am uncertain how to tie the scaling with a possible x,y coordinate.  Has anyone ever done something like this?  Am I incorrect in the use of these function possibly?

```
       -(void)buttonSelected:(id)sender
       {
          UIButton *b = sender;
          CGPoint location = b.frame.origin;

          [UIView animateWithDuration:1.3f delay:0.0f options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn animations:^{
               CGAffineTransform totalTransform =
               CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-location.x  , -location.y );
               totalTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(totalTransform, 4.0f, 4.0f);
               totalTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(totalTransform, location.x , location.y );
               [self.view setTransform:totalTransform];
           }completion:^(BOOL finished) {
           }];

       }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would either construct a transform that performed the three steps:

- move point you want to scale around to the centre of the layer;
- scale;
- move the object back so that the original centre is back in the centre.

So, e.g.

```
// to use a point that is (109, 63) from the centre as the point to scale around
CGAffineTransform totalTransform =
                  CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-109.0f, -63.0f);
totalTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(totalTransform, 4.0f, 4.0f);
totalTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(totalTransform, 109.0f, 63.0f);
```

Or, arguably more simply adjust the `view.layer`'s [`anchorPoint`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CALayer/anchorPoint). The gotcha with the second idea is that when you first adjust the anchor point you'll get an immediate transform because all other positioning is in terms of the centre.

Comment: Great, I will try this idea out, thank you for the quick response!

Comment: So i have been trying this with no luck.  What I'm doing is trying to do is zoom in on a bunch of random images on the view, but I never can seen to come out with the correct coordinates.  Ill provide some code above.

Comment: I'll write a test project to check it out, but based on your added source code: the offset is in the view's space, relative to the centre of the view. So if you wanted to scale from the top left then your `location` would be `CGPointMake(-self.frame.size.width*0.5f, -self.frame.size.height*0.5f)`. Does that improve things any?

Comment: Thank you very much for this insight.  With the above comment I was able to sort the transforms out in my head according the views center.  Much appreciated!